# How to have two outputs in a def

Tags: python-3.x

I can't add two output to def function.

I have tried many ways but it always outputs only one of them if true or false.

```
    loan_True = True
    loan_False = False
    def message():
        if loan_True == True:
            print()
            message = f"""\
        Subject: Loan Application

        Hello {Fn} {Ln}, {hurray}

        """
        elif loan_False == False:
            print()
            message = f"""\
        Subject: Loan Application

        Hello {Fn} {Ln}, {sorry}

        """
        return message
   message()
```

[Output of code that is correct and exactly what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq2E4.png)[This is the email the code sends but its wrong. i want the output in the email to be the same exact in the first pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T7JF.png)
I want the output to be what it is assigned.

Comment: What do you mean "it only outputs one of them"? Please give an example of the output you are getting, and the output you are expecting.

Comment: I believe I have to share my entire code for you to be able to see what I mean. my code sends an email to the user and I want it to choose one or the other if true but only one would output regardless if it's True False.

Comment: You don't need to share more code. Just show what is your expected output and what is actually output. What do you see on the screen after the last line? What did you want to see? Do you want `message` to contain both strings?

Comment: I added pics so you can see what i mean

Comment: Looks like the problem is your arrangement of `if` blocks. Take a look at Michael Kopp's answer, it has the structure you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose something like

```
def message(loan_allowed):
  if loan_allowed:
    return "hooray"
  else
    return "sorry"
```

I.e. use function parameters instead of global variables. If you want to use a variable in the function I would use

```
def message(loan_allowed):
  text = None
  if loan_allowed:
    text = "hooray"
  else
    text = "sorry"
  return text
```

I.e. first set it in function scope. And use a different name than the function.